# Why is this error control absolutely wrong?

Tags: c

I have this recursive function that calculates the average of a `float` array:

```c
float media(float x[], size_t n) {
    if (!x) {
        return .0;
    }
    float m;
    if (n == 1)
        return x[0];

    m = x[n - 1] / n + (n - 1.) / n * media(x, n - 1);
    return m;
}
```

My teacher told my that the error control done here is absolutely wrong and I do not understand why...

This is the part of the error control that is supposedly wrong because I shouldn't do error control here

```c
if (!x) {
    return .0;
}
```

Comment: I do not see that it is wrong to test `x` for a null pointer, but you are missing a test for `n` being zero. Your teacher should explain what the issue is; that is their job.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Perhaps because `0.0` could be a valid result? Returning `NAN` and setting `errno` to `EINVAL` would be better, IMO.

Comment: The code you are showing is not recursive. The function `media_1` is calling `media`. So unless `media` is calling `media_1`, there is no recursion.

Comment: API contracts can be whatever you want. I'd remove the `NULL` check entirely and add documentation to the function that "the behavior of the function is undefined if `x == NULL`, `n <= 0`, or the range `x` to `x + n` is not a valid `float[]`". Then it's your user's fault if they want to pass in bad data.

Comment: And *assuming* it is recursive, `x` should be checked for `NULL` only once and not in every recurrence. Not that it is terribly wrong though. This whole thing should be wrapped into another non-recursive function, which will check the parameters once and return a meaningful error.

Comment: I had written a pretty long edit to my answer to the previous question you asked about this topic. I was about to publish it and then you removed the question ... and now it appears again. I'm not falling for it again. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am much sorry but previous question was wrong formulated

Comment: @Elparaguas Well, you had edited into something that looks very similar to this.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I have not understood what you said, I don't understand what do you mean about API contracts

Comment: *" I don't understand what do you mean about API contracts"*. If your function has a set of input that leads to an error, you have three options: 1) handle the error in a well defined way, 2) ignore the error entirely, 3) put in the function's documentation what inputs are bad, and to not use those inputs.

1 and 2 are arguably your responsibility. 3 shifts responsibility to the user.

Comment: @JohnFilleau so why in my case the error is not handled in a well defined way?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, but I saw that the question was not detailed completely so I decidied to make a new post. Sorry for that, i didn't take into account the possibility that you were editing the awnser, for next time I have learnt 

Comment: _Side note:_ Are there precedence issues? Given: `x[n - 1] / n + (n - 1.) / n * media_1(x,n - 1)` I _think_ OP wants: `x[n - 1] / (n + (n - 1)) / (n * media_1(x,n - 1))` But, does it get parsed as: `(x[n - 1] / n) + ((n - 1.) / n * media_1(x,n - 1))` instead? Or, something else? Do we need more parens? And, where?

Comment: @Elparaguas you tell me if it's defined or not. I'm not telling you which of the options to choose. Follow your heart, it's what I always do.

Comment: @CraigEstey: What? No. The average of n numbers equals the last number divided by n plus the average of the first n-1 numbers scaled by (n-1)/n, which is what OP has.

Comment: Why don't you just ask your teacher?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with testing if `x` is a null pointer. Your teacher might want you to also test if `n` is `0`:

```
float media(const float x[], size_t n) {
    if (!x || !n)
        return 0;
    if (n == 1)
        return x[0];
    else
        return x[n - 1] / n + (n - 1.) / n * media(x, n - 1);
}
```

Note that with this extra test, the function can be further simplified, albeit less readable:

```
float media(const float x[], size_t n) {
    return (!x || !n) ? 0 : x[n - 1] / n + (n - 1.) / n * media(x, n - 1);
}
```

Note however that this recursive approach is only useful for illustration of recursion techniques. The recursive call is not an example of tail recursion, so the function requires `n` or `n-1` recursive calls, which for large arrays may cause a **stack overflow**.

Note also that this averaging technique tends to accumulate errors and does not fix the inherent issues with summations of values with large differences: averaging an array of `{ 1e38, -1e38, 1 }` will not produce `1`, but neither would the classic iterative sum.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the one-liner is a good idea.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree... answer updated

Comment: FYI — I already upvoted once.